# Null Pointer exception in widget

Tags: android, exception, pointers, null

team1name is initialized in the begining of the widget class

String team1name= null;

But when I return a string from the `getAcronym()` and assign to team1name, I get a null pointer exception. How do I resolve this
Here's the code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }

    team1name = extras.getString("team1name");
    team2name = extras.getString("team2name");
    team1score = extras.getString("team1score");

    team2score=extras.getString("team2score");

    player1=extras.getString("player1");
    player2=extras.getString("player2");
    extras=null;

    team1name=getAcronym(team1name);        // Null Pointer Exception
    team2name=getAcronym(team2name);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team1name, team1name);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.team2name, 
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);  

    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, remoteViews);
}


String getAcronym(String teamName){
    if(teamName.equals("Australia")){
        teamName="AUS";
    }else if(teamName.equals("Pakistan")){
        teamName="PAK";
    }else if(teamName.equals("India")){
        teamName="IND";
    }else if(teamName.equals("England")){
        teamName="ENG";
    }else if(teamName.equals("Sri Lanka")){
        teamName="SL";
    }else if(teamName.equals("South Africa")){
        teamName="RSA";
    }
    return teamName;
}
```

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger.  Either your extras bundle does not contain a string value with the key "team1name" or the value of team1name is not one that matches the choices in getAcronym (which, since you pass in a null value, will return a null value if none of the if statements are true.  As a matter of good practice, you should at least initialise the string to an empty string and have a default value returned by getAcronym.  Also declare a return value in getAcronym, set it and return it based upon the tests.

Comment: Extras bundle does have the string. And the widget is displaying the acronyms. But when I start the widget app, I get a message sorry the app has crashed, and even after that I see the app working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getAcronym(String teamName)` method does not do any null checking. Add the line:

```
if(teamName==null){
    return "";
}
```

before you start checking for the string value, and this should alleviate your problems.

Might be work checking to see why teamName is being passed through as null, if it is intentional then this solution will work fine. If you should always be sending a valid teamName through, then there is somewhere in your code before you get to your widget where it is not being assigned properly.

Also, if your strings are not constant, i.e they could conceivably be "England" or "england", you should do a comparison where the case is ignored to catch these instances.

i.e

```
 if(teamName.equalsIgnoreCase("Australia")){
    teamName="AUS";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Bundle#getString(String key)` returns `null` if the mapping is not found.  See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29).

Rather than checking for `null` in `getAcronym(String teamName)` you can alternatively use the [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) `getString(String key, String defaultValue)` which allows you to set a default value if the mapping is not found.  eg:

```
team1name = extras.getString("team1name","");
```

In your `String` comparisons within `getAcronym(String teamName)` you can also reverse the comparison to avoid the nullpointer.  This is a good habit to get into:

```
if("Australia".equals(teamName)){
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, the Nullpointer Exception happens if extras.getString("team1name") doesn't exist. You should debug your Project and confirm that the team1name variable is set with a string before you call getAcronym.

(Did you define your variables properly? String team1name = "" anywhere in your code?)